# Which scenes from the title sequences of Rick and Morty are from actual episodes?

Tags: rick-and-morty

The show *Rick and Morty* has seen a couple of different title sequences throughout its three season (so far) run:

**Which of these scenes are from actual episodes?**

They do not need to be actual copies, just depictions of the same scene. They may be from after credit scenes, such as the one where

> [Jaguar rescues Rick and Morty from Concerto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m0WQy3qF8u8&t=1m7s).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Season 1 had 50% of random shots and 50% from episodes, Season 2 and 3 were both 2/3rds random and 1/3rd from episodes.

The sequences all start with the following scene:

- Rick and Morty running from some evil frog-like aliens. Rick opens a portal and escapes but Morty trips and is left behind and attacked.

## Season 1

- Jerry shooting the Cronenbergs from the episode [Rick Potion #9](http://rickandmorty.wikia.com/wiki/Rick_Potion).
- Jerry helping Morty with his homework and then his face falling off, revealing him to be a robot. Morty is seen coming into the room in the background, and Rick stops him and takes him the other way.
- Rick and Morty being chased by the evil clones of Beth, Jerry, and Summer from [Meeseeks and Destroy](http://rickandmorty.wikia.com/wiki/Meeseeks_and_Destroy).
- Jerry trying to give birth to an alien baby who possessed his body, while Summer and Morty are holding some laser guns, waiting for it to come out.
- Hepatitis A confronting Morty and Annie from [Anatomy Park](http://rickandmorty.wikia.com/wiki/Anatomy_Park_(episode)).

## Season 2

- Morty, Jerry, Beth, and Summer eating dinner at the table and then Rick breaking through the floor in a drill machine, releasing giant mole people onto the surface.
- Rick shooting a raging Morty with an electric gun from [Look Who's Purging Now](http://rickandmorty.wikia.com/wiki/Look_Who%27s_Purging_Now).
- Jerry trapped in some kind of water capsule and Rick releasing an alien monster in there with him.
- Summer, Rick, and Mr. Beauregard jumping on the bed and having a pillow fight from [Total Rickall](http://rickandmorty.wikia.com/wiki/Total_Rickall).
- Rick and some alternate Ricks or clones of himself working in a spaceship. One of the Ricks gets electrocuted and killed. The other Ricks barely acknowledge it and then continue to work without him.

## Season 3

- An Ass-Faced Morty watching porn on "RubHub", on the computer in his room. The video involves an Ass-Faced woman pulling her panties town, revealing two faces on her rear end. An Ass-Faced Beth then enters his room and Ass-Faced Morty quickly shuts his laptop and pretends to be asleep.
- Summer and a Cyborg Summer in a space station, hiding behind a wall, equipped with armor and weaponry, preparing to attack Rick and a Gromflomite, who are having a conversation in the hallway.
- Slick Morty, Fat Morty, Glasses Morty, and Lizard Morty all sneaking out of the school from [The Ricklantis Mixup](http://rickandmorty.wikia.com/wiki/The_Ricklantis_Mixup).
- Rick and Morty tied down to the strings of a giant, grand piano, along with a few others. The other people's faces get smashed to a pulp, by the piano hammers and Rick fears his impending doom. This is the post-credits scene of [Pickle Rick](http://rickandmorty.wikia.com/wiki/The_Ricklantis_Mixup).
- Rick in a store, browsing through a section of Mortys, packaged like toy action figures. He decides between two Mortys, and when choosing one, he carelessly leaves the other behind, making him fall, face flat on the ground.

All sequences end with the same scene as well:

- Rick, Morty, and Summer being chased by a Cthulhu in Rick's space cruiser, while Summer is seen holding who is presumably the Cthulhu's baby.

---

Justin Roiland at a Q&A panel at SDCC claims that they will all feature in future episodes, however Ryan Ridley (writer) seems less convinced saying "it may take until Justin's son is doing the voices".

---

### Interesting tidbits:

- In the episode [Total Rickall](http://rickandmorty.wikia.com/wiki/Total_Rickall), the opening sequence was edited with Mr. Poopybutthole in all the scenes.
- The opening sequence did not play in the episodes [Interdimensional Cable 2: Tempting Fate](http://rickandmorty.wikia.com/wiki/Interdimensional_Cable_2:_Tempting_Fate) and [The Ricklantis Mixup](http://rickandmorty.wikia.com/wiki/The_Ricklantis_Mixup). It initially didn't play in the sneak peek airing of [The Rickshank Rickdemption](http://rickandmorty.wikia.com/wiki/The_Rickshank_Rickdemption), but was seen when the third season officially premiered.

Comment: Wait... but "Summer, Rick, and Mr. Beauregard jumping on the bed and having a pillow fight" never happened....

Comment: "Names" of "episodes" "should be" in quotes.

Comment: @ThePopMachine well that depends on your manual of style, as far as I’m aware there’s no set style guide we _have_ to use on SFF, but I’m happy to be corrected.

Comment: @Edlothiad, numerous times, I've seen edits to format names of films and TV series on italics and names of episodes in quotes.  I've always assumed this is the accepted standard.  If you don't think so, seems like a meta topic.

Comment: I think there is a single style for Film and TV series, book titles, short stories, but not episode names. I don't mine you slapping them on if you want. I don't have the patience.

Comment: Can you update for the last two seasons?

Comment: @ kaine, the pillow fight scene was in an episode. It was a flashback false memory in “Total Rickall”