# Is Cthulhu the being that chases Rick & Morty in the opening sequence?

Tags: rick-and-morty

In every opening sequence so far on *Rick & Morty*, no matter the season, we see at the end a scene where they flee in their spaceship from a Cthulhu-like creature, while Summer is holding which seems to be a spawn of the creature.

Can we state if this creature is, in fact, Cthulhu? Is there enough evidence to accept or refuse the possibility?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which scenes from the title sequences of Rick and Morty are from actual episodes?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/173243/which-scenes-from-the-title-sequences-of-rick-and-morty-are-from-actual-episodes) It's a broader question about all the scenes in the intros, however, the answer concludes it is indeed Cthulhu at the end.

Comment: That answer say that is Cthulhu, but there is no evidence at all. I know the creature resembles it, but cannot be sure. I'm asking for evidence on the fact or evidence against it.

Comment: They mention it's Cthulhu in [this interview](https://www.express.co.uk/showbiz/tv-radio/1216561/Rick-and-Morty-characters-Why-is-the-Cthulhu-not-in-any-episodes#:~:text=Cthulhu%20first%20appeared%20in%20the,ever%20since%2C%20including%20season%20four.&text=The%20character%20is%20usually%20seen,been%20seen%20in%20an%20episode.) as well as various others. Personally whilst this is an interesting question I don't think it needs to be separate from the other.

Comment: Well... that interview could be an answer to the question, as the own creators refer to the creature as Cthulhu.